# Criptografar parâmetro no link

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou tentando criptografar um parametro passado Mas não está funcionando

O que quero criptografar é `$cc['CODIGO']`

```
 <?php echo anchor('financeiro/edicao/'.$cc['CODIGO'], 
 '<span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>', 
 array('class' => 'btn btn-success')); ?>
```

Existe algum jeito de criptografar, que não esteja em desuso, para enviar como parametro no link?

Comment: Blza, vou editar minha pergunta

Comment: Já tentou usar a biblioteca [Encryption](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html)?

Comment: Então, em minhas pesquisas eu achei ela, mas ela não é somente usada no controller? eu preciso usar na view, se eu for usar na view eu teria que dar um `extends` e ficaria meio esquisito, ou estou errado?

Comment: É seguro eu usar `session` nesse caso?

Comment: Por que usar na view?

Comment: Porque ao clicar no link, me leva ao controller e o valor já está aparecendo na url. Acredito que preciso criptografar na view

Comment: E por que já não gera o valor no *controller* que servirá a *view*?

Comment: É um codigo que está dentro de um array, retornado de um controller, achei que seria mais simples eu criptografar na view